# Spark and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, spark-view-engine

I started playing with Spark in an ASP.NET MVC project. However I have an existing ASP.NET project that I can't port over to ASP.NET MVC, and was wondering if there is a way to use Spark with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Spark View Engine is awesome. And when you've tried it, there is no going back.

Spark requires either ASP.NET MVC or Castle Monorail, so I guess mixing MVC and WebForms would be the only way to start using Spark in a WebForms-project..
Start by combining WebForms and MVC (with Spark) in the same project. Then start migrating .aspx/code-behind into .spark/controls, file by file.

Remember, this refactoring could be pretty costly/time-consuming in a large project.

[Plugging ASP.NET MVC into an existing ASP.NET application](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc)